# Cannot update openssl to 1.0.2 on ubuntu docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I've done this:

```
RUN apt-get -y remove openssl

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install wget make\
    && wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz \
    && cd openssl-1.0.2g \
    && ./config \
    && make install \
    && ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl 'which openssl'
```

First I removed old openssl (1.0.1 in my case) and updated with openssl 1.0.2 but after I build the image and connect to it via bash I still get 1.0.1 version when executing opnessl version command

Answer (score 5):

You neither provided your Dockerfile nor how you start your container. Here is an example that works:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y remove openssl
RUN apt-get -y install gcc
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install wget make \
    && wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz \
    && cd openssl-1.0.2g \
    && ./config \
    && make install \
    && ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl 'which openssl'
```

Building:

```
docker build . -t openssl_test
```

Testing the version:

```
$ docker run -it openssl_test openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Comment: I didn't paste all the image...I know how to built and connect with bash on the container...the problem is when I check the version I get 1.0.1

Comment: @AlexandruCircus "when you check the version" do you mean while building or when starting a container?

Comment: I've done this: docker build -t xxxx/rc-backend:1.3 alias and after this I've done this: docker exec -it alias /bin/bash

Comment: and then openssl verision

Comment: I was stupid....I executed the version command in another container which was running, I was not executing in the image I've pasted here....stupid stupid